# Need some updated examples on how to use QListView 

Tags: c++, qt

Does anyone have any links to tutorials showing how to use QListView and how to populate it with items .. ? If I search google I can only find outdated tutorials which use classes which have been deprecated ..

Answer (score 1):

I usually just read the qt documentation as it is very good and provides the necessary information to work with a specific class (it is one of the best documented frameworks in my opinion) try and read the documentation for list view http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html and also look at the examples provided with qt in the examples directory you should find more than one which uses qlistview.